# Argument list too long and copying to Samba Share

Tags: samba, gui, cifs, cp

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit.

I'm trying to make a scheduled task copy from a directory with thousands of files to a samba share (while skipping duplicates).  I mapped my Samba share through the GUI.

The command I tried:

> cp /home/security/Brick/* ~/.gvfs/"cam on atm-bak-01.local/Brick" -n

I found this but I don't know how to change the syntax to what I need.

> find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.prj' -exec mv -t ../prjshp {} +

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I warmly advise to check out Unison: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/ . After you set it up with the graphic interface, you can easily run it by command line with `unison -batch`.

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to know how to do it through command line though for my own education purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the shell expands your `/home/security/Brick/*` with a long (too long) list of files *before* passing it to `cp`.

If you want to copy all the `Brick` directory maybe the most straightforward  thing would be:

```
cp -rn /home/security/Brick ~/.gvfs/"cam on atm-bak-01.local"/
```

using the "recursive" flag to `cp`. This will copy all the structure under Brick, too (subdirectories included).

One possibility is using a `for` loop:

```
for file in /home/security/Brick/*; 
do
cp -n $file ~/.gvfs/"cam on atm-bak-01.local/Brick"
done
```

Or using find:

```
find /home/security/Brick/ -type f -exec cp -n {} ~/.gvfs/"cam on atm-bak-01.local/Brick" \;
```

In this command, `-type f` says to select files only (no directories), then for each file executes the command specified: `{}` is substituted by the file name, and `\;` is the semicolon needed to close the `-exec` clause, escaped otherwise the shell will interpret it (and remove).

The command after `-exec` could be whatever you want (for example, instead of `cp -n` you can use `cp -av` to copy in archive mode (including timestamps and propriety) and overwriting, or you can use other commands (**but**: you should understand shell escapes, globbing and quotation before, otherwise you can do a lot of harm --- see for example ["learning the shell"](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php)).

Find is a very powerful command --- it is worth to be learned well. I have found interesting tutorials [here](http://content.hccfl.edu/faculty/wayne_pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm), [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/04/learn-linuxunix-find-command-50-practical-examples-part-i.html) and [here](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/04/learn-linuxunix-find-command-60-practical-examples-part-ii.html).

#### About doing a backup with `cp -n`:

Notice that the `-n` flag will not overwrite existing files, so if you do changes of a file in your local directory that was copied before, it will **not** be copied again... and you'll have in the backup the old version of it.

For that reason I recommend using a backup or sync utility, like [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) or [rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync), to do this work. These utilities will just update the changed files, can minimize writes (and so network bandwidth), and are generally much safer. Your backup could be solved with `rsync` by simply saying:

```
rsync -azvv  /home/security/Brick   ~/.gvfs/"cam on atm-bak-01.local/Brick"
```

(take care to not add a final "/" at the end --- or rsync will create a subdirectory Brick/Brick. Yes, `rsync` is powerful and quite temperamental sometime.)

Unison has a nice graphical interface and will also tell you if there are conflicting changes in your repository --- so this would be my preferred option.

Comment: Thanks.  I just registered today so it won't let me upvote you.  That actually works perfectly because I don't want it to be copied again.  The Ubuntu box is running "Motion" which takes pictures at a rate of 5 FPS from our security cameras when motion is detected.  This adds up quickly so I want to copy them to a NAS every half hour or so and then I'll manually delete them from the local drive once a week.

Comment: Question about the command.  After the find switches, the "exec" switch allows you to execute any command + its own switches?  And do I put *.* inside of the {} if I want to copy everything?

Comment: I edited the answer to add links and some more help.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running it and it seems to just freeze.  It's a Dual Sandy Bridge Xeon with 16GB of RAM and an SSD so I don't think it's a resource issue.  The command I typed was "find /home/cam/cam/Closet -type f -exec cp -n *.jpg ~/.gvfs/"cam on atm-bak-01.local/Closet" \;   

I triple checked the paths to make sure they were correct.  The user is cam and there is a subfolder named cam.

Comment: You can use `cp -vn` to see what's happening. Notice that there was a bad bug for gvfs and samba mounts, leading to freezes. I do not know if the fix has been backported to 12.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/1075923 .

Comment: It still freezes with the -vn.  Is there a GUI way to mount through NFS?  Our NAS supports it.

Comment: @CopyRunStart, I do not know. I used the workaround of manually mounting via cifs as explained in the bug description... and using unison to minimize data movement. Maybe this can help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountNFSSharesWithoutAutofsHowto

Comment: Unison seems to be working.  I just have to figure out how get it to run every 30 minutes and only move files in one direction.